# Afraid of / Afraid

Tags: prepositions

I've got a sentence I will always get mixed up.
And I would really appreciate it if you could help me get out of tough spot.

> I'm afraid of the time I'm with you.
>
> I'm afraid of when I'm with you.
>
> I'm afraid when I'm with you.

which one is more correct than any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite the sentences, the meaning is clearer.

One and two mean the same thing, although I wouldn't say either.

> The thing that I am afraid of is (when I am with you) or (the time that I am with you.)

In this case, when is referring to a time, "the time when x"

Sentence three means something different.

> When I am with you, I am afraid.

In this case, when is a conditional, meaning almost the same thing as "if". (Almost, but not quite)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about these all? Anyway...

> I'm afraid when I'm with you

...is the quite clear among all.

> I'm afraid of the time I'm with you

could be *okay*, but I don't think this is what you actually want

> I'm afraid of when I'm with you.

Afraid of ***'what?'*** It's not good.

Comment: I'm wondeting if the 'when' clause can be used as the object of 'be afraid' the same way as 'that' clause can.

Comment: @jihoon - You really ought to explain that **in your question**, not down in a comment on somebody's answer.